# IPTables default policy

Tags: iptables

I am slightly confused  about IPtables default policy.
Let's talk about the mangle table. let's say `ACCEPT` is the default policy on each chain.

```
PREROUTING ACCEPT
INPUT ACCEPT
FORWARD ACCEPT
OUTPUT ACCEPT
POSTROUTING ACCEPT
```

Packets that need to be forwarded will go through `PREROUTING`->`FORWARD`->`POSTROUTING` chain.

However, since the default policy in `PREROUTING` is `ACCEPT`, do the packets still traverse through the rules in `POSTROUTING` chain (or `FORWARD` chain)?

I read somewhere this:

> -j ACCEPT : the rule is accepted and will not continue traversing the current chain or any other ones in the same table.

Is this true?

I want to set marks in `POSTROUTING` chain for forwarding packets, and am wondering if it is even possible if the packets were already `ACCEPT`ed (due to the default policy) in `PREROUTING` chain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you get your quote from, my `man iptables` says:

> ACCEPT  means  to  let  the  packet through.

All the chains will be evaluated (unless one of them rejects a packet).

Using `REJECT` or `DROP` in **any** chain will cause the packet to be discarded, although that is the purpose of the `filter` table any not `mangle`. An `ACCEPT` in **all** chains will let the packet pass.

Comment: I would say that ACCEPT would accept the packet in the current predefined chain of the current table and let the packet continue through the remaining chains and tables. It can still be DROPped/REJECTed (or processed in some other way) later on.